# Enzyme can't shallow render because of an imported script using 'addEventListener'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Long story short, I have a React app that is importing a vanilla.js component. This component interacts with the DOM outside of the React app, but sometimes the React app needs to use the component. When I try and shallow render the React component that imports the Login component, Jest gets hung up on 'addEventListener' in the vanilla.js Login component:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

  90 |     }
  91 |
> 92 |     document.querySelector(config.selectors.loginModal).addEventListener('click', (e) => closeLogin(e));
     |     ^
  93 |     document.querySelector(config.selectors.loginClose).addEventListener('click', (e) => closeLogin(e));
  94 |   };
```

So I have my react app:

```
import React from 'react';
import Login from '../login';
const Component = () => {
  return (
    <h3>
      <span className='cc-stats-login-btn' onClick={(e) => 
      Login.openRegister(e, 'Statistics')}>Register</span>
      or
      <span className='cc-stats-login-btn' onClick={(e) => Login.openLogin(e, 'Statistics')}>login</span>
      to view advanced analytics and graphs
    </h3>
  );
};
```

The test for that app currently looks like:

```
document.body.innerHTML =
  '<div class="login-modal-bg">' +
  '  <div class="login-modal-close"></div>' +
  '</div>';

describe('<Component />', () => {
  test('renders', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <Component />
    );
    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

The js for the login component that Jest seems to be failing on:

```
const Login = (() => {
  const config = {
    selectors: {
      loginModal: '.login-modal-bg',
      loginClose: '.login-modal-close'
    }
  };

  [...]

  const initialize = () => {
    document.querySelector(config.selectors.loginModal).addEventListener('click', (e) => closeLogin(e));
    document.querySelector(config.selectors.loginClose).addEventListener('click', (e) => closeLogin(e));
  };
};
```

As far as I can tell based on Jest docs, all I need is a simple string as a 'mock dom' and the addEventListener should work. But all I get is the above TypeError. Any ideas?

Comment: Testability is one of reasons why direct DOM access is not a good idea in React. I would suggest to mock `document.querySelector` calls instead of mocking DOM.

Comment: I agree that the direct DOM access isn't great in React. But due to far stranger business related decisions, it's not something I can do. I tried the following to mock document.querySelector and none of it works:

`document.querySelector = jest.fn();`
`global.document.querySelector = jest.fn();`
`global.document.querySelector.addEventListener = jest.fn();`

Comment: What was the result?

Comment: always the same error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`

Comment: I added the answer how this should be done. From the code you posted it's unclear how Login works. `initialize` is supposed to be used but it isn't called anywhere. If it's called in fact, it should be called after document.querySelector has been mocked.

Comment: because `initialize` is a public function inside an IIFE, it is called at the bottom of the component. This is why the `initialize` function is called when the script is imported into the React doc. I've just decided to wrap those `addEventListener` calls in conditionals so that they are skipped if there is no DOM element. Doesn't change how the login component works and my tests won't complain. This after all a weird sort of anti pattern to React and I'm testing my React component not the vanilla js components. thanks for the help

Comment: Yes, that's an antipattern. I updated the answer. Since addEventListener doesn't even used in tested component, there's no need to even bother with it. Mock entire Login module and test it separately.

Answer (score 1):

Testing against DOM (it isn't real in Jest because it uses JSDOM) in unit tests provides additional moving parts. `document.querySelector` can be mocked instead:

```
const loginModalMock = jest.fn();
const loginCloseMock = jest.fn();

jest.spyOn(document, 'querySelector')
.mockReturnValue()
.mockReturnValueOnce({ addEventListener: loginModalMock })
.mockReturnValueOnce({ addEventListener: loginCloseMock })

const wrapper = shallow(
  <Component />
);

...
```

In this specific case `document.querySelector` is used not in tested module. The module that uses it can be mocked at the top of test file:

```
jest.mock('.../login', () => ({ openLogin: jest.fn() }));
```

Comment: I believe `Login` should be better mocked even if it was used in `Component`.